Ajax is preventing input type number min attribute
function Min(ID) {
    $Number = document.getElementById(ID);
    if ($Number.value < 1 && $Number.value !== "") {
        $Number.value = 1;
    }
}

echo '
<form id="' . $Item2 . '">
    <input type="image" src="AddToCart.png" style="margin:5px; float:left; font-size:25px;" width="65px" height="33" id="' . $EAN2 . '"
    onmouseup="KeyUp(this.id)" onmousedown="Click(this.id)"/>
    <input type="number" id = "' . $Image .'" name = "Amount" min="1" onKeyUp="Min(this.id)">
    <input type="text" name = "ID" value="' . $Item . '" readonly style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name = "Cost" value="' . $Cost . '" readonly style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name = "Kom" value="' . $Kom . '" readonly style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name = "EAN" value="' . $EAN . '" readonly style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name = "Type" value="Food/Slatko" readonly style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name = "Image" value="' . $Image . '" readonly style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name = "Account" value="' . $_SESSION["Account"] . '" readonly style="display: none;">
</form>';

<script>
echo "
<script>
$('#" . $EAN2 . "').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'ItemProcessor.php',
        data: $('#" . $Item2 . "').serialize(),
    })
})
</script>";

I have this form here. It normally stops the user from inputting less than 1 into the input, but because of the ajax code it sends it regardless.
I have tried adding a function onkeyup that checks the value and sets it to 1 if it's lower than it, but the user can press the image while not releasing the key to still have a negative number.

I would recommend using valueAsNumber instead of value

I'm not able to submit the form/invoke the AJAX call with the code given if the number is below 1. (And for that I need to disable the Min function first to be able to get a negative value in the first place. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Instead of keyup, i would use input since it check as soon as an input is detected :
<input type="number" id = "' . $Image .'" name = "Amount" min="1" oninput="Min(this.id)">

But in any case you should check the value again in ItemProcessor.php and not spend too much time on the front side, as there are lot of ways to go through a JS or HTML restriction (you're sending data with Ajax, using GET method, it would be really simple)

I was looking for something like oninput, but couldn't find it. Thanks!

I would suggest just adding the validation before the .ajax call. It will validate it regardless of the event:
$('#" . $EAN2 . "').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
const amountInput = $('#" . $Image . "');

// Validate that the amount is at least 1
if (parseInt(amountInput.val()) < 1 || amountInput.val() === '') {
    amountInput.val(1); // Set it to 1 if it's less than 1 or empty
    alert('Amount must be at least 1.');
    return; // Stop the form from submitting
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'ItemProcessor.php',
    data: $('#" . $Item2 . "').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('Form submitted successfully:', response);
        // Additional handling for the response can be added here if needed
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('Form submission failed:', error);
    }
});
});


Use the build-in form validation and then do the AJAX request on the submit event. It even gives the user a hint about what is wrong with the value. For all required form fields set the required attribute.
Not that I think it is a good idea, but you can also listen for the input event on the amount input and then change the value to 1 if the entered number is smaller than 1. I find it annoying.


const form01 = document.forms.form01;

form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'ItemProcessor.php',
    data: $(e.target).serialize()
  });
});

/*
form01.amount.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if(e.target.valueAsNumber < 1){
    e.target.value = 1;
  }
});
*/
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form01">
  <label>Amount: <input type="number"
    name="amount" min="1" required></label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>



